# Erro selenium python, não consegue achar elemento

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando usar selenium para fazer um script em python para automatizar o login no Twitter. Porém, estou sempre recebendo este erro: Unable to locate element. Qualquer elemento da página aparece esse erro, tento achar pelo xpath.

O meu código:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://twitter.com')

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
user.send_keys(afonsobritto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar somente:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/label/div/div[2]/div/input
```

Lembre-se que a função send_keys() recebe parâmetro do tipo str (String)

Recomendo que veja esse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JKkEr_1-v0&ab_channel=CaveiraTech)

Answer (score -2):

Olá, algum tempo atrás eu estudei para fazer uma automação web de login, e enfrentei um problema similar.

Ao estudar o problema, verifiquei que estava copiando errado o XPATH.

Sendo assim, sugiro verificar se está inspecionando o campo correto para coletar o XPATH. No meu caso eu aperto CTRL+SHIFT+C, seleciono o campo e após abrir aparecer o campo destacado na guia Inspecionar, clico com o direito > copy > XPATH. Então assim colo no código.

Espero ter ajudado.